# How to minimize $\max(x_1, x_2)$ and $x_1^2 + 9x_2^2$ subject to constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

My textbook came up with a solution without explanation. I'm looking for a systematic way of solving the following optimization problems and similar ones (by hand), because I'm drawing a blank:

```
minimize
```

$$\max(x_1, x_2)$$ and after, $$x_1^2 + 9x_2^2$$

```
subject to
```

$$2x_1 + x_2 \ge 1$$
$$x_1 + 3x_2 \ge1$$
$$x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0$$

BTW the answer is $\left(\dfrac{1}{3}, \dfrac{1}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Edited question to reflect second objective $f(x_1, x_2)$ function example and fix title.

Comment: @Magdiragdag the question wants to minimize objectives in the form $f(x_1, x_2)$ over the given constraints in R2.

Comment: Oh, it really wants to minimize the maximum of $x_1$ and $x_2$...

Comment: Did you draw a picture? At least of the area you're optimizing over?

Comment: What is meant by minimize $\max(x_1, x_2)$ and $x_1^2 + 9x_2^2$?  Do you mean minimize $\max(x_1, x_2) + x_1^2 + 9x_2^2$?

Comment: @Jared just two different problems (same constraints), sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us enter in the [Karush–Kuhn–Tucker framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions), 
with
$$
f(x,y) = -\max(x,y);\\
g_1(x,y) = 2x+y-1;\\
g_2(x,y) = x+3y-1.
$$

The Lagrangian is
$$
L(x,y,\lambda) =
-\max(x,y) + \lambda\cdot g(x,y)
$$

and the solution is, **in the region $x\neq y$** (where $L$ is smooth):
$$
\begin{cases}
0&=&-1_{x>y} + 2\lambda_1 + \lambda_2  \\
0&=&-1_{x<y} + \lambda_1 + 3\lambda_2 \\
0&=&\min(\lambda_{i} , g_{i}(x,y)), & (i=1,2).
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, both $\lambda_i =0$
and the system has no solution.

**In the region $x = y$,**

$\max (x,y) = x$.
$$L(x,y,\lambda) =
-x + \lambda\cdot g(x,y) =: M(x,\lambda).
$$The new system for $M$ is:

$$
\begin{cases}
0&=&-1+ 3\lambda_1 +4\lambda_2\\
0&=&\min(\lambda_{i} , g_{i}(x,x)), & (i=1,2).
\end{cases}
$$
As we can't have $
g_1(x,x)=0=g_2(x,x),
$ either $\lambda_1=0$ or $\lambda_2=0$, then 
$$
x\in\{1/3, 1/4\}.
$$
But if $x=y=1/4$, $2x+y<1$ and the point is not an admissible solution.

Then the solution is
$$
x=y=\frac 13;\\
\min_{g_{1,2}(x,y)\ge 0} \max(x,y)
= -\max_{g_{1,2}(x,y)\ge 0} (- \max(x,y))
\\ = \max(1/3,1/3) = 1/3.
$$

---

For the second problem,
the equations are 
$$
\begin{cases}
0&=&-2x + 2\lambda_1 + \lambda_2  \\
0&=&-18y + \lambda_1 + 3\lambda_2 \\
0&=&\min(\lambda_{i} , g_{i}(x,y)), & (i=1,2),
\end{cases}
$$
hence  $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\neq (0,0).$

If $\lambda_2 = 0$:

$$
\begin{cases}
0&=&-2x + 2\lambda_1   \\
0&=&-18y + \lambda_1  \\
1 &=& 2x+y
\end{cases}
$$

then $x=18y, y=1/37, x = 18/37$. Then $x+3y = 21/37<1$: this is not the solution.

The solution is such as
$$
\begin{cases}
0&=&-2x + \lambda_2   \\
0&=&-18y + 3\lambda_2  \\
1 &=& x+3y
\end{cases}
$$
then $x=3y, y=1/6, x=1/2$.

Comment: For the first solution, I'm not understanding the last equation of the systems, with 0 = min(...). Where did that come from? The others I understand from gradient of the lagrangian

Comment: it means that if $\lambda\neq 0$ then the inequality becomes an equality; and that $\lambda \ge 0$ in general (this is actually more clear in the [french version](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditions_de_Kuhn-Tucker)).

Comment: Is it still obtained from differentiating the lagrangian with respect to the remaining variables, i.e. lambda 1 and 2?

Comment: when you write "Is it still obtained", what is 'it'?

Comment: The final equation in the systems, 0 = min(...)

Comment: Roughly, the sign of $\lambda$ is obtained because you want to be inside the domain and not outside. And if $\lambda\neq 0$ then the lagrangian is modified to take care of the constrain with equality, then there must be equality in it.

Comment: Oh I see, from KKT (the French wiki states this) the min = 0 equation combines positivity and complimentary slackness.